# Можно ли оптимизировать скрипт?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, сделаны (к сожалению) таким образом:

```
`table_1`    
    +id+slug+
    + 1+  zz+
    + 2+  zy+
    + 3+  zx+
    + 4+  za+
    + 5+  zb+
    ...

`table_2`    
    +id+parent_id+slug+
    + 1+        1+  zz+
    + 2+        1+  zy+
    + 3+        1+  zx+
    + 4+        2+  za+
    + 5+        2+  zb+
    ...
```

Есть скрипт (для переноса данных меджу БД)

```
...подключения к БД, SELECT из `table_1`...
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$slug = $row['slug'];
if(in_array($slug, [
        'zz',
        'zy',
        'zx',
    ]))
    {
        $another_id = 1;
    }elseif(in_array($slug, [
        'za',
        'zb',
    ])){
        $another_id = 2;
    }
```

`another_id`, по сути, `=== parent_id`
Проблема в том, что обе таблицы имеют около 200 полей, выбирать вручную `SELECT DISTINCT slug FROM table_2 WHERE parent_id=1` все `zz,zy,zx` и ложить в `if`, наверное, не очень правильно.
upd: в результате `$another_id` буду `INSERT'ить` в некоторое поле таблицы новой БД

Comment: Добавьте запрос к бд и что в результате должно быть.

Comment: Если нужны только различные `slug` и их `parent_id` то можно сделать `parent_id, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( slug ) ) FROM ... GROUP BY parent_id`

Comment: да, вы правильно поняли. т. е. нужно добавить еще одно подключение к `table_2` и уже с ним работать? `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table_2";
$result = $conn->query($sql2);`

Comment: А куда вы будете инсертить, эта БД на другом сервере или на этом же. Если на том же, просто другая таблица то все операции можно делать без php в самом MySQL

Comment: @Mike на другом сервере

Comment: table1 и table2 на разных серверах? Если на одном то можно просто сделать join и получить parent_id, если на разных то нужно делать доп подключение в другой бд и выбираеть оттуда отдельным запросом.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что не внес ясность сразу. `table_1` и `table_2` на одном сервере, инсертить буду в `table_3` на другом сервере

Comment: @Tarasovych А нет возможности подцепить table_3 к первому серверу, используя FEDERATED Engine? всё бы стало на порядок проще... И мне вообще не сильно понятно горячее желание все данные протащить через клиента.

Comment: `table_1` связана с `table_2` через `table_1.id = table_2.id` или `table_1.slug = table_2.slug`?

Comment: @Akina это пока не входит в рамки моих знаний, но если это проще, япопытаюсь разобратся @vikolyada в том и проблема, что `table_1` и `table_2` никак не связаны. есть только одинаковые колонки `slug` (так, как вы написали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно, через что связаны таблицы `table_1` и `table_2`. Если связь `table_1.id = table_2.id`, то запрос такой:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.slug,
    t2.parent_id as another_id
FROM table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Если должна быть связь `table_1.slug = table_2.slug`:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.slug,
    t2.parent_id as another_id
FROM table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN `table_2` AS t2 ON t1.slug = t2.slug
```